# Equivilent of -d in curl with requests in python

Tags: python, rest, post

Right now I am using the OC Transpo API (http://www.octranspo1.com/developers/documentation) in my python application.

For my requests to their API to retrieve data I have this

```
class OcTranspoGetter:
#import credentials from file, my credentials are not in sample file,
#they can be gotten from http://www.octranspo1.com/developers/
def __init__(self):
    credFile = open('../config/logins.ser')
    credentials = pickle.load(credFile)

    self.apiID = credentials['apiLogin']['apiID']
    #self.apiKey = credentials['apiLogin']['apiKey']
    self.payLoad = {'apiID':self.apiID,'apiKey':self.apiKey}

    print self.payLoad

#Get live data
def getLiveData(self,bus,stop):
    self.payLoad['stopNum'] = stop
    soapData = requests.post('https://api.octranspo1.com/v1.2/GetRouteSummaryForStop',data = self.payLoad)
    return soapData
```

Though when I run the code with:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'modules')
from octranspo import OcTranspoGetter
import utilities

octranspo = OcTranspoGetter();
soapData = octranspo.getLiveData('3017','94')

print soapData.text
```

I get the error Error: application with id="" was not found

From this and url that is returned from soapData, it looks like that request.post() is using a get method still for requesting to the API. The service requires post, as the documents on it say to use the curl -d command. From what I have seen of the request docs (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart) what I am doing should make a post request, but it is not. Is there something I am missing in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the first parameter should be `appID`, not `apiID` as you have it.